# Use connection QueryTables without Create/Add it

Tags: vba, excel

Everyday I access a different FTP file in Excel via QueryTables. I don't want to maintain this querytable in Excel's connection.

I tried to find a way to download this file using QueryTables without save a connection. But I didn't find a way to do this.

Nowadays I use QueryTables.add() and Delete it after my use, but the connection don't desapear. 
My code:

```
Dim qt as Variant

Set MySheet = Sheets("MyTempSheet")
Set qt = MySheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=path, Destination:=Cells(2, 1))

With qt
    .Name = "MyTempConn"
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SaveData = False
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

qt.Delete 'won't work.
```

PS: I don't want to delete all query (code below) because I have some Connection that I want to keep

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets   
  For Each qt In ws.QueryTables   
    qt.Delete   
  Next qt   
Next ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qt.Delete` wont work, because `qt` is not the actual query table, but the addition action to the QueryTables stack. since there is no use defining qt, you can skip that part (no need to use variant type, either), and you can go `MySheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=path, Destination:=Cells(2, 1))`

to delete your query you can either delete the top of the QueryTables stack `MySheet.QueryTables(1).Delete` (current query index is always 1, pushing back the older queries to higher indexes), or, if you want to make sure it is your query, you can do

```
For Each qt In MySheet.QueryTables
    If Left(qt.Name, 10) = "MyTempConn" Then qt.Delete
Next qt
```

this checks only MySheet's queries. the `Left` part is there because, if there was an addition with the same name before, the new query will be renamed to `MyTempConn_1` and so on. This code will delete all previously added connections with the same name.